# Subviews becomes nil - UIStoryboard

Tags: ios, iphone, uistoryboard

I'm trying to load a `MKMapView` from a controller in `UIStoryBoard`. I can get the `MapViewController` object, but subviews inside the it becomes `nil`.

[image]

All subviews becomes `nil`. Here `mapview` (object of `MKMapView`) becomes `nil`.

[image]

I have connected mapView in `UIStoryBoard`.

Comment: have you created outlet of mapview? Show the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you present view controller or load view explicitly, the subviews in that view controller will be nil.

So, the simply way to trigger your view controller to initialize all subviews, is to call

`self.mapViewController.loadView()`

or

`self.view.addSubviews(self.mapViewController.view)`